# A question on the Chow group on stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a separated Deligne-Mumford stack finite type over the ground field.  Then there is a Chow group $A_*(X)$ of $X$ which is well-behaved under flat pull-back, defined as follows.

Let $\mathcal{W}_*$  be the sheaf of rational equivalences on the small etale site $X_{et}$, defined as $\mathcal{W}_*(U):=W_*(U)=\oplus_{V\subset U} R(V)$ for every scheme $U\in X_{et}$. Here $V$ runs over all integral closed subschemes of $U$, and $R(V)$ is the field of rational functions on $V$. And we define another sheaf $\mathcal{Z}_*$ on $X_{et}$ as $\mathcal{Z}_*(U):=Z_*(U)$ the free abelian group generated by all integral closed subschemes of $U\in X_{et}$.

There is a morphism of sheaves $\partial_X: \mathcal{W}_*\to \mathcal{Z}_*$ given by
$$\partial_X(U): W_*(U)\to Z_*(U), f\in R(V)\mapsto \mathrm{div}_V(f)$$
for every $U\in X_{et}$ and integral closed subscheme $V\subset U$.

The Chow group $A_*(X)$ is then defined as the cokernel of map $\Gamma(X_{et}, \mathcal{W}_*)\to \Gamma(X_{et}, \mathcal{Z}_*)$ induced by $\partial_X$.

Question: Is it true that for any $\alpha\in A_*(X)$, if $\alpha|_U=0$ for $\underline{every}$ $U\in X_{et}$, then $\alpha=0\in A_*(X)$? Or at least $\alpha=0\in A_*(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$?

If $X$ is the global quotient of an algebraic space by a finite group, it is not hard to see this is true. But in general, such DM stack $X$ is only etale locally of such form, or just generically (admits a finite generically etale covering)...

I think $\alpha=0\in A_*(X)$ is equivalent to saying that $\alpha|_Y=0\in A_*(Y)$ for every open substack $Y\subset X$. So I tried to prove that $\alpha|_U=0\in A_*(U)$ for every $U\in X_{et}$ implies $\alpha|_Y=0\in A_*(Y)$ for every open substack $Y\subset X$. But I'm not quite sure about this argument...